# Linux Mint Cinnamon doesn't detect Windows 10 during installation

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, windows-10, grub

I have been struggling with this problem for two days now. I Googled a lot of posts, but I just can't solve this. So I have clean installed Windows 10 (BIOS is normal, no UEFI – most people fix it with that) on 320 GB HDD partition 1. I left the second partition around 90 GB for Linux.

Than I tried few Linux distributions and they don't detect Windows 10 during installation. I picked manual setting of partition, I picked free space, added swap partition, home partition and `/` (root) partition, and below where I can pickup drive for boot loader by default is `/dev/sda` which should be correct according all posts I've read. But the problem is I see there new 3 Linux partitions (that's ok) and I see `/dev/sda1` partition (Windows partition) and it says "Windows recovery environment (loader)" instad of "Windows 10".

I messed up my Windows completely like this, so now I'm trying to ask for help before I do the same again. I installed like this two days ago, and then I couldn't boot Windows any more, and updating grub always just shows that recovery environment. Boot-repair didn't help either, so I ended up with wiping the disk completely. What can be reason for this? No compatability with Windows 10 or?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following steps see if it helps:

1.First install windows 10 and leave some free space for the linux.

2.After the installation live boot into a linux say ubuntu.

2.1. Click on Install Ubuntu if it detects your os then good to go and choose the first option "Install Alongside windows 10".

2.2.If it doesn't recognizes your windows installation then go ahead and install manually by partitioning the free space.Don't touch windows partitions.

3.Now after the boot if it boots into windows download http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/.

4.Click on add new entry and choose your OS and disks.Done.

5.If it boots up into Linux [Add Windows boot entries after installing Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/637005/add-windows-boot-entries-after-installing-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

"Windows recovery environment (loader)" is the correct option to start your Windows 10 bootup. There is a way to change it to "Windows 10 Startup" or whatever name, but you do not need to do it. If your Windows 10 worked OK before installing Linux Mint, then it should work properly after picking that option after your dual-boot install.